# Scale node when tapped or dragged not functioning consistently

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want my SKSpritenodes to scale up(enlarge) when they are tapped on and dragged around the screen. When the user removes touch input they need to scale down on the last location. This is the code I'm using now to achieve this effect:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let card = atPoint(location) as? Card
        if card?.cardType == .main{
            card?.zPosition = 30
            card?.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.3, duration: 0.15))
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let card = atPoint(location) as? Card
        if card?.cardType == .main{
            card?.zPosition = 30
            card?.removeFromParent()
            addChild(card!)
            card?.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.15))
        }
    }
}
```

Card is a class which I've defined which inherits from SKSpriteNode.

The problem seems to be that sometimes when I touch the sprite nodes, they don't scale up, other times they do. When I drag them around, it seems the animation appears extremely laggy. Also, when I drop the node(i.e remove touch input), the scale down effect doesn't occur consistently either(sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't). What is going on? If you guys need more of the source code, let me know.

Comment: For your scaling issue,  You are stacking up SKActions.  Either remove the previous action or assign a key.

Comment: For your dragging issue, I do not see any `touchesMoved` function, but look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179326/moving-multiple-nodes-at-once-from-touch-with-spritekit/41185256#41185256 on how to handle the drag

Comment: You can also combine your if with your let to get rid of the optionals '?'. `if let card =  atPoint(location) as? Card,card.cardType == .main`, and in your touched end method, instead of doing a remove and add, just do `card.moveToParent(self)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not copy and paste this answer, try to do the work yourself and compare your code with this answer.

How to fix the scaling problem:

When you call run action, the new action does not cancel the previous action, so what is happening is you are running both actions at the same time, which can conflict.  Instead, use a key to remove the previous action.

How to fix the dragging problem:

You need to preserve what node is being dragged in the touch began method.  Then when you do your dragging, you will know what position to set.

Also look at how I have cleaned up the code to reduce lines and remove the '?' in a lot of your variable calls.  Before you go and use ? or ! on a variable to solve your problem, check to see if there is a better way to handle the flow of the code. Use ! only when you can 100% guarantee that a nil can never happen and will be inefficient to wrap in a temp variable.  Use ? only when you are expecting the code to continue even if the variable is nil and will be inefficient to wrap in a temp variable.

If you happen to need a variable to be in the same scope as the function you are working with, then you may want to consider using a `guard`.  The way guard works is it will exit the current scope if certain criteria are not met, so for example you hit a point in your code where you say card must exist beyond this point, then you do `guard let card = atPoint(location) as? Card`.  For more info on guard, see http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/ to get a better understanding of how it works.

```
var movableCard : Card?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if let card = atPoint(location) as? Card, card.cardType == .main{
            card.zPosition = 30
            movableCard = card
            //Not sure what node this card is suppose to move to
            card.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.3, duration: 0.15),withKey:"scaling")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if let card = movableCard{

            card.position = location
        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if let card = movableCard{
            card.zPosition = 30
            card.moveToParent(self)
            movableCard = nil
            card.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.15),withKey:"scaling")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!