# Disabling User Interaction On Sprites

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

So i am currently making a game and i have a sprite that can be dragged around the screen but as soon as move the sprite once i want the sprite to be unarguable and not to respond to user interaction.
Currently this is what i have tried

```
func addp1Cards() {

    let player1 = Card(cardType: CardType(rawValue: player1_cards[p1int])!)
    player1.size = CGSize(width: player1.size.width * 0.25, height: player1.size.height * 0.25)
    player1.position = CGPoint(x: -10.4927577972412, y: 615.942138671875)
    player1.zPosition = CGFloat(zpos)
    player1.name = "\(player1_cards[0])"
    print(player1_cards[0])
    addChild(player1)

    p1int += 1
    }


   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        print(location)

        let rotR = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 0.15, duration: 0.2)
        let rotL = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -0.15, duration: 0.2)
        let cycle = SKAction.sequence([rotR, rotL, rotL, rotR])
        let wiggle = SKAction.repeatForever(cycle)

        if turnBool == true {

        if let card = atPoint(location) as? Card {
            card.zPosition = CardLevel.moving.rawValue
            addp1Cards()
            if touch.tapCount > 1 {

                return

            }

            if card.enlarged { return }

            card.run(wiggle, withKey: "wiggle")

            card.removeAction(forKey: "drop")
            card.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.3, duration: 0.25), withKey: "pickup")

                        }
        }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if let card = atPoint(location) as? Card {

            if turnBool == true {

            if card.enlarged { return }
            card.position = location
        }
        }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if let card = atPoint(location) as? Card {

            if turnBool == true {


            turnBool = false
            addp1Cards()
            if card.enlarged { return }

            card.zPosition = CardLevel.board.rawValue

            card.removeAction(forKey: "wiggle")
            card.run(SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0, duration: 0.2), withKey:"rotate")

            card.removeAction(forKey: "pickup")
            card.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.25), withKey: "drop")

            card.removeFromParent()
            addChild(card)

                card.flip()
             self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "\(player2_cards[p2int - 2])") { card2y, stop in
                   card2y.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

           }
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: So you want to be able to tap on it, which would be a start of dragging, and drag it around while second tap on a same sprite should be ignored? But you should be still able to drag the sprite until you remove the finger off the sprite?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving multiple nodes at once from touch with SpriteKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179326/moving-multiple-nodes-at-once-from-touch-with-spritekit)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution.

I added a array of card names containing names of cards that had been moved, and if the card name was that i was trying to move matched a name in the array i would not allow to moving code to run.

Here's what it looks like,

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if let card = atPoint(location) as? Card {

            if turnBool == true {
                if Movedcards.contains(card.name!) {

                } else {
                    if card.enlarged { return }
                    card.position = location
                }
        }
    }
}
```